# Custom environment for sequent calculus proofs

Tags: environments, logic, bussproofs

I'm using the package `bussproofs` to typeset sequent calculus proofs with LaTeX. Whilst I'm more than satisfied with the results, writing the code is cumbersome. Thus, I'd like to define a custom environment to make my life a little easier. Normally, I would write code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{prooftree}
\def\fCenter{\mbox{\Large$\Rightarrow$}}
\Axiom$\alpha  \ \fCenter\ \alpha$
\Axiom$\beta   \ \fCenter\ \beta$
\RightLabel{FEA}
\BinaryInf$\alpha \to \beta, \alpha \ \fCenter\  \beta$
\RightLabel{UEA}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, \alpha \  \fCenter\ \beta$
\RightLabel{UEA}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, (\alpha \to \beta )\land \alpha \  \fCenter\ \beta$
\RightLabel{Contract}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha \  \fCenter\ \beta$
\RightLabel{FES}
\UnaryInf$\  \fCenter\  (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha \to \beta$
\end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like to change now is this:

- the environment is centered by default but the alignment can be changed by an optional argument
- shorten the command names: `\Axiom` becomes `\ax`, `\RightLabel` becomes `\rlab`, `\LeftLabel` `\llab`, `\UnaryInf`, `\BinaryInf`, `\TrinaryInf`, `\QuaternaryInf` and `\QuinaryInf` become `\inf1` to `\inf5`, respectively
- `\ax` and the inference commands take the respective sequent as a mandatory argument; this argument is in math-mode by default so you don't need dollar signs
- instead of `\ \fCenter\`, `=>` is used to denote the alignment and automatically prints `\Rightarrow` (as defined in the very first line of the environment).

In the end, the proof displayed above should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{scproof}
  \ax{\alpha => \alpha}
  \ax{\beta  => \beta}
  \rlab{FEA}
  \inf2{\alpha \to \beta, \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{UEA}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{UEA}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{Contract}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{FES}
  \inf1{=> (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha \to \beta}
\end{scproof}
\end{document}
```

I'm new to LaTeX and afraid this is too big of a project to handle on my own. Is there someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation as you desire.

I'd never do `\mbox{\Large$\Rightarrow$}` with additional spaces around, so I used `\implies`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vitus@ax}[1]{\vitus@@ax$#1$}
\def\vitus@@ax$#1=>#2${\Axiom$#1\fCenter#2$}
\newcommand\vitus@inf[2]{\vitus@@inf{#1}$#2$}
\def\vitus@@inf#1$#2=>#3${%
  \ifcase#1\or
  \expandafter\UnaryInf\or
  \expandafter\BinaryInf\or
  \expandafter\TernaryInf\or
  \expandafter\QuaternaryInf\or
  \expandafter\QuinaryInf\fi
  $#2\fCenter#3$%
}
\newenvironment{scproof}
 {% make the new user interface
  \let\ax\vitus@ax
  \let\inf\vitus@inf
  \let\rlab\RightLabel
  \def\fCenter{\implies}%
  % start the prooftree
  \prooftree
 }
 {\endprooftree}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
\def\fCenter{\implies}
\Axiom$\alpha  \fCenter\alpha$
\Axiom$\beta   \fCenter\beta$
\RightLabel{FEA}
\BinaryInf$\alpha \to \beta, \alpha \fCenter \beta$
\RightLabel{UEA}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, \alpha  \fCenter\beta$
\RightLabel{UEA}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, (\alpha \to \beta )\land \alpha  \fCenter\beta$
\RightLabel{Contract}
\UnaryInf$ (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha  \fCenter\beta$
\RightLabel{FES}
\UnaryInf$ \fCenter (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha \to \beta$
\end{prooftree}

\begin{scproof}
  \ax{\alpha => \alpha}
  \ax{\beta  => \beta}
  \rlab{FEA}
  \inf2{\alpha \to \beta, \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{UEA}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{UEA}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha, (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{Contract}
  \inf1{(\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha => \beta}
  \rlab{FES}
  \inf1{=> (\alpha \to \beta) \land \alpha \to \beta}
\end{scproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you also now a way of forcing the arrow to always be in the middle of a line? In lines where there is only α, the arrow is way too high. Try `\ax{\alpha => \alpha}`, `\inf1{\lnot\alpha , \alpha =>}` , `\inf1{\lnot\alpha , \alpha \land \beta =>}` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @VitusSchäfftlein I don't think the package provides for that.